# SQL: Comparing Ordering by Closest value

Tags: sql

I've got a database with information:

```
----------------------------------------------
| HighValue | LowValue | CurrentValue | Code |
----------------------------------------------
|  20       |    6     |      19      | GHI  |
|  10       |    2     |      3       | ABC  |
|  8        |    8     |      8       | JKL  |
|  15       |    8     |      9       | DEF  |
----------------------------------------------
```

I want to find out which codes that have the Current Value  closest to the lowest value:
Probably in order, like this:

```
----------------------------------------------
| HighValue | LowValue | CurrentValue | Code |
----------------------------------------------
|  8        |    8     |      8       | JKL  |
|  10       |    2     |      3       | ABC  |
|  15       |    8     |      9       | DEF  |
|  20       |    6     |      19      | GHI  |
----------------------------------------------
```

How can I compare a column with another column like this?

Answer (score 1):

```
Select * 
FROM yourtable
ORDER BY ABS(CurrentValue-LowValue)
```